# Find an item on the root view model in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel, root

I have modelled my view models as POJOs and page wide functions in my main view model. I want to display the department name selected.

My select binds to the list of types on the root view model. The selected item is bound to an observable property on the Department.

How do I get retrieve the name from the array on the root view model and display it?

```
<div data-bind="with: department">
Department Type
<select data-bind="options: $root.departmentTypes, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: departmentTypeId, optionsCaption: 'Select....' "></select>

<!--I want to display the name that was selected here-->
<span data-bind="departmentName"></span>

</div>


var Department = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.departmentTypeId = ko.observable();
    self.departmentName = ko.computed(/* using the departmentTypeId search the list of departments on the view model and display the name that was selected*/ );
};

var VieWModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.saveDepartment = function(){ /* save self.department to the server using ajax */ };

    self.departmentTypes = [
        { id: 1, name: 'core' },
        { id: 2, name: 'support' },
        { id: 3, name: 'income' },
    ];

    self.department = new Department();
};

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to retrieve the `departmentName` whenever a `Department` has been selected?

Comment: I need to post the Department object to the server with the id of the selected department but want to display the name of the selected department on another part of the page. I was thinking that departmentName should be a computed to look up the name from the array on the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You have to use observableArray. No need to use "with" keyword.

```
var DepartmentType = function (id, name) {
     var self = this;
     self.name = name;
     self.departmentId = id;
}

var Department = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.department = ko.observable();

    self.departmentName = ko.computed(function() {
         return self.department().name;
    }, this);

   self.departmentId = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.department().id;
   }, this);

};
var VieWModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.departmentTypes = ko.observableArray([
            { id: 1, name: 'core' },
            { id: 2, name: 'support' },
            { id: 3, name: 'income' },
        ]);

        self.selectedDepartmentType = ko.observable();

        self.saveDepartment = function () {
            //check if self.selectedDepartmentType() is not null
            //call your server sending self.selectedDepartmentType().id
        }
    };
```

HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: departmentTypes, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedDepartmentType, optionsCaption: 'Select....' "></select>

 <!-- check if selectedDepartment is not null, then show its name -->
 <span data-bind="text: selectedDepartmentType() ? selectedDepartmentType().name: 'unknown'"></span>
```

More information at: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-3-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-not-just-strings

Comment: Fabio - I will be submitting the whole Department object to the server so need to have the selectedDepartmentId set. The value binding on the select has to set the selectedDepartmentId on the Department object - but I want to display the name on another part of the page for the user to see which one was selected

Comment: self.selectedDepartment represents the selected department. To submit the departmentId, use self.selectedDepartment().id in your javascript function. To display the name use self.selectedDepartment().name. Remember to always check if self.SelectedDepartment is null. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Department is a stripped down idea of a much larger object in my model. It get's populated using a form and then submitted to the server. I only need to store the id of the selected department type. I need to get access to the list of department type on the ViewModel object from my department ko computed function

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem...But I believe that creating a class for DepartmentType should solve your problem. Take a look at my edited answer.